# How do I get past the EULA screen in the terminal when trying to install Pipelight?

Tags: pipelight, debconf

I am in the process of installing Pipelight (according to the directions I found online). I typed the `sudo apt-get install pipelight` command everything is fine until I get a EULA from Microsoft in the terminal from which I cannot "escape" to advance to the prompt where I need to type in the `sudo pipelight-plugin --update` command.

Comment: try the tab key

Comment: It baffled me the first time too.

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the EULA agreement.